# iPhone App with Web Service Access

Tags: iphone, web-services

I have been asked to write a compliment website/service for an iPhone app.

The app creates images. The author wants these images to be uploaded onto the server, into their personal storage area. These images need to be able to be pulled down to the iPhone later for editing. The user will be able to use the website as well to see these images.

I have yet to decide (or understand) what the best way of implementing this would be. And with no experience with iPhone development I have no idea what it can actually handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading and downloading images is trivial using NSURL and associated classes. You just open the URL, write/read the file and you're done.

See [The URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) to get started.

Comment: I mean the server side, rather than the iPhone side. But thanks, I'll be able to pass that onto the app developer.

Comment: Theres nothing special that you need to do for an web server to make it work with iPhone. Just your standard upload and download features will work fine. The only thing you really need to do is to format the site for the small display area of the iPhone screen but that is also fairly standard these days.